# error with pocketsphinx configuration

Tags: iphone, cmusphinx

When I start to configure pocketsphinx on mac, 3 errors occurred on the terminal with this command in SphinxBase

```
./build_for_iphone.sh simulator
```

and these are the errors

> bitvec.lo Error 1
>   install-recursive Error 1
>   install-recursive Error 1
>   install-recursive Error 1

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Run `make clean` before you switch from simulator build to device build. System doesn't know that it needs to clean files of the different architecture.

Comment: but this error occurred after typing  build commend for simulator 

, that's mean i can not build for device because the errors not solved